# Can't get Raspbmc to browse samba shared folders

Tags: linux, samba, raspbmc

I can't get Raspbmc to browse my shared folders on my Windows 7 computer that is in the same network. When trying to add a networklocation, I get 'connection timed out'

Things I have tried:

- I deleted all the workgroups in the network.
- I've set my network type to 'home network'
- I've opened up all the setting under 'change advanced sharing
  settings' both under 'public' and 'home or work'
- I shared a folder on my Windows 7 computer via -> share with ->
  specific people -> everyone
- I installed the latest nightly build
- I executed 'sudo apt-get install samba' in the terminal, witch stated
  the latest version of samba was already installed
- I am able to ping the pc with the shared folder from the pi.
- Tried turning off windows firewall
- I've tried making windows users and filling in those credentials when
  connecting

I have a second computer also running windows 7, XBMC on this pc is able to see my shared folder.
I'm fairly technical but really inexperienced with Linux, is there something that I am missing?

Also don't know if this is related but i cant connect via putty, I get 'connection refused'

Comment: Could you try to connect from your Raspberry Pi via the command line to Windows? You could do this in 2 steps, first list the available shares and then connect to it. 1. List shares:  `smbclient -L "\\<windows-hostname>" -U "<workgroup>\username"` you can skip the `-U ...` if you do not need a user. 2. Connect: `smbclient "\\<windows-hostname>\<share-name>" -U "<workgroup>\username"` you can also skip the `-U ...` if you do not need a user. What are the outputs or error messages?

Comment: Can't connect to WHAT from WHERE via putty?  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The few times I have had this problem with RaspBMC the solution has been to reboot my SMB server and/or Raspberry Pi itself. After that I was able to access the SMB shares without any problem.

Comment: Rebooted the server and was able to connect

Answer (score 0):

I found increasing the memory available to the LanMan server in Windows solved my problem.
The answer is described here: http://froebe.net/blog/2013/08/20/howto-samba-protocol-negotiation-failed-nt_status_insufficient_resources-solved-windows-xp-2k8-win7-win8-win2012/

> Change the following registry keys:
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory
>   Management\LargeSystemCache -> DWORD value 1
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size ->
>   DWORD value 3
>
> Then restart the computer, or run services.msc and restart the
>   "Server" service.